# Verify Linux software packages before installing RPM

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild

I have an RPM file that need to be installed, before installing I want to check the version of packages contained within it. If the package is already installed I can use `rpm -qi` to know the version number, but what option do I use to find out the version if the package is not installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-p` option can be used to direct a query at an uninstalled package.

```
rpm -qip package.rpm
```